# Crystal Report Formula missing

Tags: crystal-reports

## Problem:

The formula name 'Decimals' gone missing after I comment-out the code block.

## Step by step illustration:

1.When I open my crystal report file it prompt this error.

[image: 1]

2.After that when I try to F5 (Refresh) to get the output, it shows this error.

[image: 2]

3.Then I comment out the whole code block. The error didn't appear anymore but now I cannot find back the formula.
[image: 3]

Please guide me on how to revert back the changes. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the report 'works', is because you are viewing a copy with saved data.  When you refresh the report, CR tries to rebuild it.  It can't find that DLL, so it raises an exception.  Find a copy of that DLL and add it to the appropriate, shared directory (the directory is version-specific).

If you can describe the logic, perhaps we can help you eliminate the need for the UFL.

Comment: I manage to get the DLL from another PC and now it works fine. Now I believed that the only problem was caused by not having this DLL in my PC. Thank you so much after all.